# Button generating a cross sum

Tags: function, actionscript-3, button

I'm looking for a tip for a AS3 script, have no idea how to start there

Button, if clicked the function is executed, which outputs a predefined value as the cross sum of a number string.

Example:

Cross sum should be 10

By clicking on the button, the function generates the number 55 or 82 or 37 or 523, ie numbers with the cross sum 10

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now..... 
the function calculates a number, with the crosssum 50

```
function berechnen() {
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000)
var sum = String(rand)
var qsum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
    qsum += Number(sum.charAt(i));
}
if (qsum == 50) {
    summe.text = String(sum);
} else {
    berechnen()
}
```

}

Comment: Don't know why someone down-votes an effort to help yourself...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way using `%` (modulo) instead of a string. You could write that into one line like this:

```
while (sum != 0) { qsum += sum % 10; sum /= 10; }
```

The trick is that modulo will give us only the last digit of the longer number, then we `divide by 10` to trim off that last number (from longer) and we re-read a newer ending digit of the long number.

Example:
Long num = `1234`, so each trim gives, `4` then `3` then `2` then `1` and we'll sum them up each time.

usage:

```
myInt = cross_sum(50); //makes myInt hold answer result of function (where ExpectedValue input is 50).
```

and the supporting function...

```
function cross_sum( ExpectedValue: int ) : int 
{
    var rand :int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000)
    var sum :int = Math.abs( rand );
    var qsum :int = 0;

    while (sum != 0) 
    {
        qsum += sum % 10; //get last digit of sum...
        sum /= 10; //trim down sum by 1 digit...
    }

    if ( qsum == ExpectedValue ) { return rand; } //# stop here and give back "rand" as answer result.
    else { cross_sum( expectedValue ); } //# else if wrong, try again...
}
```